# realm exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Missing argument to Not

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a `realm` `database` and I want to do a `query` as below.

- I have a list of object with primary key is Id field.
- Now I have a list of Ids and I want to get list of object which not
  has id in the list.

Example:

- In database I have a list : 1,2,3,....9.
- I have a list id is: 1,2,3.
- I want to get 4,5,6...9.

So I do a query as below:

```
protected <T extends RealmObject> List<T> getListNotContainIds(Class<T> model, List<Long> idList, String fieldName) {
    checkValueOfPortalRealm();
    RealmQuery<T> query = portalRealmInstance.where(model);
    if (idList != null) {
        query.not().beginGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                query.equalTo(fieldName, idList.get(i));
            } else {
                query.or().equalTo(fieldName, idList.get(i));
            }
        }
        query.endGroup();
    }
    return query.findAll();
}
```

Then, I got the exception :.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Missing argument to Not
>                                                                                at io.realm.internal.TableQuery.validateQuery(TableQuery.java:94)
>                                                                                at io.realm.internal.TableQuery.findAll(TableQuery.java:449)
>                                                                                at io.realm.RealmQuery.findAll(RealmQuery.java:1434)

I guest that I have some problem with my `query`, some one can help to correct it ?

Comment: You have to put the `not()` at the **end** of the query statement, not at the beginning of it.

Comment: By the way, you should refer to this answer it can help you: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3154

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
protected <T extends RealmObject> List<T> getListNotContainIds(Class<T> model, List<Long> idList, String fieldName) {
    checkValueOfPortalRealm();
    RealmQuery<T> query = portalRealmInstance.where(model);
    if(idList != null && idList.size() > 0) {
        boolean isFirst = true;
        query = query.beginGroup();
        for (long id : idList) {
            if(!isFirst) {
                 query = query.or();
            }
            query = query.notEqualTo(fieldName, id);
            isFirst = false;
        }
        query = query.endGroup();
    }
    return query.findAll();
}
```